# Instalar Big Calendar en React Js 18.1.0

Tags: reactjs

La instalación desde npm es: `npm i react-big-calendar`

En el repo oficial: `pm install --save react-big-calendar`

El resultado que me da:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: calendar-mern@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.14.0 || ^17" from react-big-calendar@0.40.1
```

Por lo poco que entiendo es que hay un conflicto de dependencias y que no lo puede resolver con la versión 18.1.0 de React... ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Esta es la segunda parte del error que me sale:

> pm ERR! node_modules/react-big-calendar
> npm ERR!   react-big-calendar@"*" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency   resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-05-20T15_01_24_417Z-debug-0.log

Comment: ¿ _pm_ o _npm_? Por otra parte: ¿hiciste caso a lo que dice el mensaje? **Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps**

Comment: npm, en el segundo fué error de copiado.  No, no lo hice porque no entendía bien la respuesta. Ahí probé con --legacy-peer-deps y me apareció la misma respuesta pero con --force me dejó instarlar el paquete aunque con varios WARN. Gracias!

Comment: Entonces, ponlo como respuesta y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.